# Find the adjoint operator of $T$ on $P_2(R)$

Tags: linear-algebra

On $P_2(\mathbb{R})$, define the the inner product $$\langle p(x),q(x) \rangle =\int_0^1 p(x)q(x)dx.$$  Operator $T$ satisfies $T(a+bx+cx^2)=-bx$ for any $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$.  Find the adjoint operator of $T$.

Here what I have thought is  to use the equation $<T[p(x)],q(x)>=<p(x),T^*[q(x)]>$ and think $P_2(\mathbb{R})$ as a three dimensional vector space. Anyone can help with it?

Comment: You're on the right track---what part of the process do you need help with?

Comment: @Travis   I don not know how to solve it in 3 dimensional space, what is the representation of transformation matrix for  $T$ and $T^*$?

Comment: First, can you choose a basis for $P_2(\Bbb R)$ and compute $T$ w.r.t. it?

Comment: @Travis   the basis is $\{1, x, x^2}\$, so T is [0,0,0; 0, -1,0; 0,0,0]?

Comment: Yes, that basis is certainly natural, and that's the right transition matrix for it. Now what? (BTW, one option is to choose a basis orthonormal w.r.t. the inner product. This is more work at this point in the process, but it has the benefit that the inner product is the standard one w.r.t. this basis, in which case one can form the matrix representation of the adjoint just by taking the transpose; this is *not* the case for a general basis.)

Comment: @Travis   now we should find out the orthogonal basis for this inner product? {1,x, x^2} is not orthogonal.

Comment: The Gram-Schmidt algorithm is built to achieve exactly that. (If you'd like to continue this discussion, perhaps let's do so in chat?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23796/discussion-between-shine-and-travis).

Comment: @Travis  I found the orthogonal basis is {1, x-1/2, x^2-x+1/6}, so the transformation of T under this orthogonal basis is [0,0,0;  0,-1,1; 0,0,0]. So I just need to take the transpose of that matrix?

Answer (score 0):

You have $\langle p, q \rangle = \int_0^1 p(x)q(x) dx$.

Let $b_k(x) = x^k$, for $k=0,1,2$.

Let $\phi:P_2(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be given by $\phi(x \mapsto a+bx+cx^2) = (a,b,c)^T$. $\phi$ is a linear bijection, and
$p = \sum_k [\phi(p)]_k b_k$.

Then $\langle p, q \rangle = \langle\sum_k [\phi(p)]_k b_k, \sum_k [\phi(q)]_k b_k \rangle = \sum_{i,j} [\phi(p)]_i [\phi(p)]_j \langle b_i, b_j \rangle$. Since $\langle b_i, b_j \rangle= {1 \over i+j+1}$, we can write
$\langle p, q \rangle = \phi(p)^T A \phi(q) $, where $[A]_{ij} = {1 \over i+j+1}$ (which is symmetric and positive definite).

Note that $\phi(Tq) = P \phi(q)$, where $P$ is zero everywhere except $[P]_{22} = -1$.

Then $\langle p, T(q) \rangle = \phi(p)^T A P\phi(q)$. If we let
$C=A^{-1} P^T A$, then we have
$\phi(p)^T A P\phi(q) = (C\phi(p))^T A \phi(q)$.

If we let $$T^*(x \mapsto a+bx+cx^2) = x \mapsto ( 45c+60b+90a) {x}^{2}-( 48c+64b+96a) x+9c+12b+18a$$
then
$\phi(T^* p) = C\phi(p)$, and
$\langle p, T(q) \rangle = \langle T^*(p), q \rangle $.